# Jenkins on EC2 AWS service: getting '[ec2-user: command not found' error

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I am installing Jenkins on EC2 instance. I have followed all the steps from the AWS document provided at https://d1.awsstatic.com/Projects/P5505030/aws-project_Jenkins-build-server.pdf . I am stuck at the first step under *Download and Install Jenkins* section. On running `[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update –y` in ubuntu terminal I am getting error '*[ec2-user: command not found*'. I have created an instance similar to the type mentioned in the AWS guidelines and I am trying to install Jenkins on EC2 using Ubuntu 16.0.4 version.

Comment: `yum` is the package manager for RHEL-based operating systems, such as RHEL, CentOS, Amazon Linux, etc.  The equivalent for Ubuntu is `apt`; `yum` is not available on Ubuntu.  You need to find instructions for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to linux but I figured it out and jenkins is installed and running on EC2 now.